# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_3_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1500, 1)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_3_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1500, 1)
>   `

```
history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels, 
epochs=50, verbose=0, validation_split=0.25)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'])
plt.show()
ValueError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-8779b6fa958d> in <module>()
1 history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels, 
2 epochs=50, verbose=0, validation_split=0.25)
4 plt.figure()
5 plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
```

`

Comment: your model expects 3-dimensional input, but your input data does not have a 3 dimensional shape. For more information you should post the code that creates your model.